# Slide Up/Down animation not working correct in second Time

Tags: android, android-animation, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have one layout in Top position and this view is hide first time.I would to do slide up and down animation with programmatically.I wrote code and this code working perfect only first time
Here is it

```
public void cutomTabDropDownAnimation(LinearLayout view, boolean isSlideDown) {
    TranslateAnimation animate;
    if (isSlideDown) {
        animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                0,
                0,
                0,
                view.getHeight()); // toYDelta
    } else {
        animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                0,
                0,
                view.getHeight(),                 
                0); // toYDelta
    }


    animate.setDuration(300);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    animate.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    view.setAnimation(animate);
    if (isSlideDown)
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);


}
```

In second time, first view is showed and then animation started ,but not correct,view hidden.
Here is a xml file source

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f2f2f2">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/customTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/u_four_tab_1"
            android:textColor="#405a97"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/u_four_tab_2"
            android:textColor="#d4d4d4"
            android:textSize="16dp"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#801d7aed" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customTabLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_layout_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/u_empty_package"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/package_grey" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I mean customTabLayout linear layout in xml file.How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is causing the strange behaviour is this part of your code:

```
if (isSlideDown)
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You need to set the visibility of your view after the animation ended or before it started (depending on the context)

```
    animate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (isSlideDown){
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    if (!isSlideDown){
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

    }
});
```

Comment: I changed but nothing else @Jaja

Answer (score 0):

Change to INVISIBLE instead of GONE.

Try this :

```
 if (isSlideDown)
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```